# ListLinePlot x-axis units label

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, labeling

If I want to label the $x$-axis of a `ListLinePlot` , how do I do that?

There are two types of label:

- a **units label** which would go to the **right of the axis**,

and then potentially you could have an

- **axis label below it**.

What would be the way to enter both types of text?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 6], AxesLabel -> {"meter\ndistance", "y"}]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Labeled` is quite short solution:

```
Labeled[ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 6], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
        {"x label", "y label"}, 
        {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   Row[{
  Rotate[Style["Second label Y", 16, Bold], 90 Degree],
  Spacer[10],
  Column[{
    ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 6], 
     AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16, Italic], Style["y", 16, Italic]}, 
     ImageSize -> 350],
    Style["Second label X", 16, Bold]
    }, Alignment -> Center]
  }]
```

You should obtain something of this sort: [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably late to mention, but I always add frame in my plot

```
`ListPlot[t1b9, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0.045, 0.05}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t_1","Energy (kJ/mol)"}]`
```

which produces the following graph, `t1b9` is just the data collection I used for my plot

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: For clarity, please provide the complete code and resulting plot with two labels per axis, as the other two answers do.